# as much / many as

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I'd like to know whether **many** or **much** should be used in the following:

> a. A whale could weigh as **much** / **many** as two tons.
>
> b. The company bought as **much** / **many** as two tons of cotton.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between *as much* and *as many* is basically the same as the difference between *less* or *fewer*.

If you are referring to *something that you can count*, for example a *number* of people or animals, you would use "as many".

**Example:**

> There are not as many red squirrels as there used to be.
>   **also:**
>   There are fewer squirrels than there used to be.

But if you are referring to *a quantity of something* which is *not countable*, for example, a quantity of water or other liquid, you would use "as much".

**Example:**

> There is not as much water in the lake as there used to be.
>   **also:**
>   There is less water in the lake than there used to be.

Just remember that if a quantity of something is grouped into containers, or by some other collective means that you can count - for example *glasses of water* then you use the appropriate language for the *collective noun*.

Finally though, when referring to *measurements* of something, as in your example of weight, you should use the appropriate language for the thing that you are measuring.

**Example:**

> A whale could weigh *as much* as two tons.

This is correct because you can't "count" weight. You *measure* it. The same goes for your other example:

> The company bought **as much** as two tons of cotton.

This is for the same reason that you can't "count" cotton and you can't "count" weight; **but** if the cotton came in *boxes* it would be different:

> The company bought as many as two *boxes* of cotton.

Because you *can* count boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can count tons, kilos, pounds, ounces and so forth, with units of weight it is the total weight as a single quantity that governs the usage here.  Use **much**, because that's what 99.9% of native speakers do.